# Using a global ResourceLoader in UWP/Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I use a resw-file to store literal strings in my app and I access them with

```
(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader()).GetString("resourceName");
```

I find this a bit cumbersome and would like to have a global resource loader, e.g. in a static class:

```
public static class ResourceLoader
{
    private static Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();

    public static string Get(string name)
    {
        return loader.GetString(name);
    }
}
```

That way I only have one instance of the ResourceLoader and it's easy to access. Is there anything that speaks against doing it like this? It seems to work in my app, but I don't want to miss anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no documented drawback on using a global ResourceLoader.
Although you should get an instance using the static method GetForViewIndependentUse() instead of the constructor;
this method give you an instance of ResourceLoader that doesn't depend on any specific context so you can retrieve resources from your app from anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if it helps, but this is a class I use for loading strings from a ResW in code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;

namespace ProjectName.Services
{
    public sealed class ResourceService : ObservableObject
    {
        private ResourceService() {}

        public static Task<ResourceService> CreateServiceAsync ()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new ResourceService());
        }

        public Task<string> GetResourceStringAsync (string stringname)
        {
            try
            {
                var resourceloader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
                return Task.FromResult(resourceloader.GetString(stringname));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public Task<string> GetResourceStringAsync (string resource, string stringname)
        {
            try
            {
                var resourceloader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView(resource);
                return Task.FromResult(resourceloader.GetString(stringname));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I initialize it in App.xaml.cs in the OnLaunched event with:

```
this.ResourceService = await ResourceService.CreateServiceAsync()
```

Then consume it with:

```
var stringtoget = await App.ResourceService.GetResourceStringAsync("resourcename", "stringkeyname");
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use async methods? I don't think getting the resource strings takes so...

Comment: Just from preference really, so the rest of the code (which is usually async/await) is consistent.